# Associate and display additional data with each form row in a Django formset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I'd like to be able to display additional information like a text label with each row in a Django formset.

Example/usecase:

User picks 5 rows in a model that would he would like some action performed. A popup appears that displays a 5 form formset some additional information (that are model instance methods) based on the 5 rows chosen previously. User does some input, submits forms and 5 new rows are created in a different model.

Currently I'm thinking about passing a dictionary of this additional information in separately and somehow associating them with each form in the formset. But to get that to work I need to be able to set unique initial data for each row so I can use a hidden field for instance (I've posted another question for that specific issue).

It would be neater if I could associate the additional information with the form in a manner that would allow me to iterate through the form on the template or call 'as_table'.

Answer (score 3):

This one stumped me for a bit too.  Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Edit: I posted this a while back and didn't realize half the post was eaten due to bad formatting.  Corrected code below.

```
<TABLE>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form.id }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.FirstName }}</td>   <!-- This is a normal, editable field -->
                <td>{{ form.instance.LastName }}</td> <!!-- 'instance' is your actual Django model.  LastName displays the text from the last name field -->
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</TABLE>
```